# How to add slideshow field in drupal 7 content types

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there any easy way to integrate slideshow as field in drupal 7 content type? I can do it using third party module, but I dont want to use anyother module, i want to add the field by adding or modifying come content.

If yes, please say how.?

Comment: Check this site out: whathaveyoutried.com. Then please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try searching on google?
The first result when searching 'drupal slideshow field' on google links to:
http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

Comment: I dont want to use, module, i WANT TO edit the theme portion. Please let me know if there is  a way out.

Comment: I see the question has been updated with this information...If you want a simple way, use the module, otherwise override the template file or theme function and add your own javascript for the slideshow.

Comment: That is what i am asking. i want to override the template file. So which file should i be overriding exactly. If you know this then help before voting down.

Comment: If that is what you are asking...Why didn't you ask that in the first place? I suggest you you take a look at the site linked to in the first comment under your question.